# How do I repair ceiling joists separating from beam/hanger?

Tags: ceiling, attic, hanger

We purchased our house about 4 years ago, and I've recently noticed that in the attic, several of the ceiling joists are not fully "bearing" on the hangers. This is a house build in the late 50's, so likely this isn't anything new, but for peace of mind, I'd like to get it reinforced. I've thought about using lateral ties, but don't know that's the best plan.

Do I need to fix this and if so, how?

*Ignore the wiring, that's a whole other issue I'm fixing...*

[image]

[image]

Comment: @JimStewart, the OP did acknowledge that there were wiring issues he's planning on addressing, too. ;)

Comment: With a house built in the late 50s, it's most likely that these hangars are retro fit. At that time, the joists would have been simply nailed through the rim into the end of the joist and/or toe nailed in.

Comment: Also, I added a question to the body for you, as is expected at this site.

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that those joists were never fully put on the hangers to begin with.

It's extremely difficult to place a joist in a slot that is exactly large enough for it down to the millimeter. If you don't go down exactly parallel it will bind up and you have to employ various means of persuasion. Adding a quarter inch of margin makes it drop right in.

There is margin in the hangers to account for builders not flushing up the joist. If you dig down into that insulation a bit you will be able to measure how much metal is supporting the wood.

Comment: Given these are ceiling joists, but also provide some lateral support for the roof structure, I'm more concerned about outways/lateral movement than the ceiling support. You are correct, they are still firmly on the metal hanger, but the side nails are no longer attached firmly into the wood.